# Xcode error - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: xcode

I have this error in XCode:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"Parser::Parser(char const*)", referenced from:
  ___cxx_global_var_init in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

Very common reason is using a static library that is compiled for 32 bit only.

Comment: How to find out which library is built in 32-bit architecture? I've 12-14 Frameworks/Libraries in my project.