# muParser in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, muparser

I want to use the muparser library in an c++ application. I use Xcode und Mac Os X El Capitan to code. The library was installed using HomeBrew as `brew install muparser` but if I compile [this sample code](http://muparser.beltoforion.de/mup_example.html#idExample) I get errors of the type `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`. I searched a bit and found that it might be due to [static libraries which are compiled only for 32 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579262/xcode-error-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64). Question: Can I fix this somehow by either telling HomeBrew to install the 64 bit variant or directly in Xcode?

Comment: Homebrew is x86_64 by default unless you add `--32-bit`. Problem is somewhere else

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)